# Lua regex to replace curly braces

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I want to replace curly braces and it's word inside i.e. `something in here {uid} {uid2}` to `something in here :id :id`.

I tried the following:

```
local v = "something in here {uid} {uid2}"
local regex = "^{([^}]+)}"

print(v:gsub(v:match(regex), ":id"):gsub("{", ""):gsub("}", ""))
```

But it doesn't work. However, it does work when I remove "something in here ". Please help.

Comment: `^` means *start of string*. Remove it if you do not want to restrict the match to only appear at the start.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not global? I mean for the url `/api/{parentId}/{childId}`, I got ` /api/data/lookups/something/childId`. That childId wasn't replaced.

Comment: No, `^` does not mean global. Also,  I think all you need is `v:gsub("{[^{}]*}", ":id")`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/HGHD3V)

Comment: Thank you so much for that @WiktorStribiżew. Can you tell me how can I replace all the words with the curly braces? I am new to lua patterns so I'm still learning. It would be a big help if you guide/tell me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh sorry didn't see a demo there

Comment: Yes, I added a link a bit later. Is it all you actually need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace all substrings inside curly braces that do not contain any other curly braces inside you may use

```
v:gsub("{[^{}]*}", ":id")
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/HGHD3V):

```
local v = "something in here {uid} {uid2}"
res, _ = v:gsub("{([^{}]*)}", ":id")
print(res)
-- something in here :id :id
```

The `{[^{}]*}` pattern matches a `{`, then any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`, and then `}`.

**Alternative solutions**

- `{.-}` will match `{`, then any 0+ chars as few as possible (`-` is a lazy quantifier), and then a `}` char (see [this demo](https://ideone.com/RklIfp))
- If you have a balanced amount of nested curly braces you may use `v:gsub("%b{}", ":id")` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/Z1Nz07)), `%b{}` will match substrings inside nested curly braces.